# Sigma-algebra & random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

How can I find $Y$ which is not a constant function and prop?

$$\Omega=(0,1)$$

$$F=\sigma{(0,\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{3},1)}
 ={\phi, \Omega, (0,\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{3},1), (0,\frac{1}{3}],[\frac{1}{2},1),(0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup[\frac{1}{2},1),(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})}$$

($\forall a,b  \{w \in \Omega \mid Y(w) \in (a,b)\} \in F$  and $Y:\Omega \to\mathbb{R}$)

I couldn't find any examples of random variables Y except for constant functions.

The elements of $F$ have the same interval each other, so I can't distinguish between the inverse images of them.

Comment: $Y=1_{(0,1/2)}$, for example.

Comment: this is hard to read, sorry. Try learning some MathJax (tutorials on this site)

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why (0,1/2)?

Comment: @cyk: I introduced MathJax in your question, but it still looks like rubbish. Please edit and make your question more readable, using the mentioned MathJax.

Comment: I'm outside right now, so I'll revise it as soon as possible I'm sorry